# Change the value of an element in a PFUser Object of type Array, in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm new to Parse server. 
First, I create a multidimensional array as an object on Parse server

```
let day1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
let day2 = ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"]

let jan = [day1, day2]
let feb = [day1, day2]

let calendar = [jan, feb]

let user = PFUser()
user.username = userNameTextField.text
user.password = passwordTextField.text
user["Calendar"] = calendar
```

[image]

What I want is to be able to do a PFUser query and change the value of calendar [ 1 ] [ 0 ] [ 1 ] from "two" to "zero". I've gone over Parse's documentation, but I'm just confused on how I could accomplish this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure Parse Query can query those inner arrays, unfortunately.  You could always do a Parse.Query.each on the User class and check each one but this is inefficient if you have a large amount of users. Do you want to do this on the server, or from a swift app?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I’m not sure how to answer your question, as I’m new to this. I am building a swift app, so I guess from the app? Not sure what you mean by doing it on the server.

Comment: Wherever you're hosting your parse-server, you can add cloud code functions that you are then able to call from all clients.  This is particularly useful if you're doing both Android and iOS apps, as you don't have to recreate logic on both clients, you can just call the cloud code method, and do the logic once in Javascript.  Are you trying to update all users' calendars with this? Or is it just the user you already have? If you could, provide more context on what you're changing here / what triggers it and I can point you in the appropriate direction.

Comment: Thanks again! I just want to update the user-who-is-using-the-app’s calendar

Comment: In that case you shouldn't need a query at all.  `PFUser.currentUser()` should return the currently signed in user, and then you can use `object(forKey:"Calendar")` to access the calendar. Cast it as an `Array<Array<Any>>` and update values as desired.

Comment: You'll of course need to save the object afterwards for the update to take effect on the server and to persist later on.

Comment: @JakeT. I added an Array :)   `let userCalendar = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "Calendar") as! Array<Array<Any<Array>>>`          Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that accomplishes what I was trying to do:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bedTimeTextField: UITextField!

    var userCalendar = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "Calendar") as! Array<Array<Array<Any>>>

    func setBedTime(int: Int) {

        userCalendar[1][1][int] = 0

        PFUser.current()?.setValue(userCalendar, forKey: "Calendar")

        PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground()

    }

    @IBAction func cmonButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if bedTimeTextField.text != "" {

            let textFieldInt: Int? = Int(bedTimeTextField.text!)

            setBedTime(int: textFieldInt!)

            let userCalendar = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "Calendar") as! Array<Array<Array<Any>>>

            print(userCalendar)

        }
```